# I have 400 Bad Request in REST.php on line 79 implementing GMAIL Api PHP

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I am getting 400 Bad Request in REST.php on line 79 implementing GMAIL Api PHP

I have used below code to implement:

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey(API_KEY);
$client->setClientId(OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client_email = MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID;
$private_key = file_get_contents('MYP12.p12');
$scopes = array(
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                    'https://mail.google.com'
                );
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);
$client->setApplicationName("Gmail Sample");
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
 //Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$token = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($token);
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$user = 'me';

$date_last = date('Y-m-d');
$newdate = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($date_last));
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', $newdate);

$q = " 'after:".$newdate."'";
$messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user, ['maxResults'=>1000 , 'q'=> $q]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($messagesResponse);exit;
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https‍://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1000&q=+%27after%3A2017-12-26%27&key=[API_KEY]:
>   (400) Bad Request' in
>   C:\wamp\www\google\google_calendar\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 79

Comment: is `[MY_API_KEY]` the key you send to google or have you replaced the key for this post?

Comment: The key  send to google.

Comment: This won't work, you need to create an google account and obtain your own api key

Comment: actually, i didn't send API key it will automatically call by Gmail.
Using OAuth 2.0 credential it will work perfectly but using service account I am getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace API_KEY, OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET, [MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID]  with your credentials.

```
$client->setDeveloperKey(API_KEY);
$client->setClientId(OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client_email = '[MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID]';
```

Comment: I knew i didn't post my original credentials